# Auto router update - now cannot access linux machine via Wifi network

Tags: linux, networking, router, kodi

My router, Fritz!Box 7530, had an auto update 3 days ago. Since then I cannot connect to my linux machine from my Mac or my Android S20 FE phone. I have Kodi running on the linux laptop (A) and the Kore remote from my phone was working 100% before the router update.

I have scratched in the router and the only thing that I could find was a tick box allowing devices on the LAN to speak to one another. That box was ticked an I left it as such.

**Router**: Fritz!Box 7530

**Kodi**: 20.2.0. Compiled: 2023-07-01

**Machines**:
Two linux mint machines (Linux mint 21.1, Cinnamon version:5.6.8, Kernel: 5.15.0-76-generic). Lets call these A (mine) and B (other)
Mac (Ventura 13.4.1)

I can ssh from A to B, but only if I use the name, can not when using IP. IP is correct, I do a copy paste to make sure I have the right numbers. B had ssh server installed before the router upgrade.

From B I can ssh to A, but again only using name, not IP. I can also ssh from A to B on the name only.

I cannot ssh from Mac. Not on the name or IP. It does not find either A or B.

I cannot ping any of the machines, but pings are generally switched off so that says nothing.

I have Kodi running on A and use to access it with Kore from my phone. Worked well until the router upgrade.

I don't have a firewall running on either Linux machines, but when I do iptables --list I do get a return output. Everything seems open except Chain Forward. The iptable set up was pretty basic until I enabled ufw and tried to add some rules to allow my kodi ports to get through. Also tried to open ssh ports. I have since switched off ufw.

I don't know just enough about networking to break stuff, so kind of challenged on this front. I looked at a number of the network commands, but i don't know how to interpret the output.

When I do a nmap from the mac I can actually see A and the ports, but it reports the port is filtered. It does tell me what is running on the port.

More things I tried:

1. Tried to connect from my phone to A with Kore
2. Tried from B to A via ssh and vice versa - This works but only if I use the machine name as per the router
3. Checked basic network commands but I cannot interpret the output (I don't know what to look for)
4. Combed through the router set up looking for possible switches
5. Changed A's ip and re-registered it on the router
6. Can't remember all of the other stuff I tried

Comment: I did a backup of the router, did factory settings restore, restored the backup and viola. All working again.